# Custom @RequestParam return messages and conditional parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am not really a fan of the default messages used if the @RequestParam fails to validate (type, required, etc). I would like to use my own custom messages.

I also have several parameters that are conditionally required.

I am thinking to achieve this I will need to roll my own HandlerMethodInvoker. resolveHandlerArguments using a modified version of RequestParam.

Is there an easy way to 'inject' my new version of HandlerMethodInvoker into Spring? If not, will I need to create my own DispatcherServlet and the various pieces between it and HandlerMethodInvoker?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to replace the validation messages then you only need to add some properties to the message files.

For more details read Spring [Reference Chapter 5.3 Resolving codes to error messages](http://5.3%20Resolving%20codes%20to%20error%20messages) and  have a look at the java doc of [org.springframework.validation.DefaultMessageCodesResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DefaultMessageCodesResolver.html), it explain the used message codes very vell.